# How to notify a user through Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a real-time messaging app (not chat app like WhatsApp, I have one publisher and a lot of subscribers).

I want it to send a notification when I get new message.

That's my code(with errors):

```
mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Message message = postSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            messages.add(0, message.getTitle() + '\n' + message.getMessage(), NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = //cannot resolve symbol 'mBuilder'
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) //builder (android.content.Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (anonymous com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_he_digita_homepage)
                            .setContentTitle(message.getTitle())
                            .setContentText(message.getMessage()); //')' expected
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, updates.class); //Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener, java.lang.Class<com.inbar.amit.ksharet>)'
                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this); //create (android.content.Context) in TaskStackBuilder cannot be applied to (anonymous com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener)
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(updates.class);
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
                            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                            0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
                            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(124453245, mBuilder.build()););

        }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

I'm using Android Studio.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You have a code for the client app, but do you have an App Server?

Comment: @AL. I think I don't have...I'm a bit new with programming apps. Can you explain me what an App Server is?

Comment: You are using Firebase, which is the app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that `onChildAdded` will be called for each child already in the database, and each child added after you start listening, so you will end up with a notification for every message in your database already.

**UPDATE**

So you need to create a new function for this code, because it doesn't work in a listener class. Here is code that should work for you:

```
mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Message message = postSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
        messages.add(0, message.getTitle() + '\n' + message.getMessage());
        sendNotification(message);

    }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Outside of other methods, add this method:

```
public void sendNotification(Message message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) 
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_he_digita_homepage)
            .setContentTitle(message.getTitle())
            .setContentText(message.getMessage());
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, updates.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(updates.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(124453245, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: I don't have any function called Add() in my Message.(did you mean messages.add?, because it's adding the item to the array.
what is ResultActivity.class?
what should I put in mId?

Comment: Yeah, I meant `messages.add()`

Comment: ResultActivity.class is the class you want it to open when your notification is tapped. `mId` is an integer that you can use if you want to edit the notification later. It can be any integer, so long as it is somewhat unique so that another app does not accidentally edit it.

Comment: it doesn't get it

Comment: What doesn't get what?

Comment: Post the errors to your question and we can help you solve them.

Comment: You need to put the code that I answered with in the `messages.add()` function, not after it, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: It is in the messages.add() function

Comment: I see what you mean. I updated my answer with new code for you to try.

Comment: So,
it works. it sends a notification. is there any way to do it on the background? (when the data is uploaded).it sends the notification only when you enter to this activity.

Comment: For this, you need to look into services. Services are background code that runs for your app. Android has a good introduction here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html (Also, if my code worked, don't forget to mark my answer as correct)